# C# increment when creating new object via Array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, constructor

So I am adding/creating objects within Console class via an array:

```
string[] console_available = { "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
for (int i = 0; i < console_available .Length; i++)
        {
            Classes.Console console = new Classes.Console(console_available[i]);
        }
```

In the class itself I have int console_id which I want to increment but for some reason it only increments it once with the below constructor:

```
public int ConsoleID { get; set; } = 0;
public string Available { get; set; }

public Console(string available)
    {
        ConsoleID++;
        this.Available = available;
    }
```

So in essence its all "1 Yes" where I need it to be "1 Yes", "2 Yes", "3 Yes".

I don't really want to go down the route of having multiple lines of code to create the objects, e.g.:

```
Classes.Console console  = new Classes.Console("Yes");
Classes.Console console2 = new Classes.Console("Yes");
Classes.Console console3 = new Classes.Console("Yes");
```

Comment: In your loop you create five objects, but throw them away, as you don´t use them anywhere.

Comment: Why not adding a second parameter (the ConsoleID) to the constructor?

Comment: `ConsoleID` is specific to each instance. Your constructor is adding to the variable but every time you declare a new instance, it just sets it back to 0 since that's hard coded. Make it into a `static` variable like @Sean answered to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a static variable that you increment and store in a member variable:

```
private static int _ID = 1;

public int ConsoleID { get; set; };
public string Available { get; set; }

public Console(string available)
{
    ConsoleID = _ID++;
    this.Available = available;
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you!

Comment: Accepted now! Had to wait another 5 minutes as cannot accept an answer right after the question was posted :)